# Why one child class alone flings error ? does order matter?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I was reading about diamond inheritance problem in java . So wanted to know how other languages have solved and found that c++ has solved it .
And I found this [How does virtual inheritance solve the "diamond" (multiple inheritance) ambiguity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/how-does-virtual-inheritance-solve-the-diamond-problem) . Then I tried this code in [online c++ compiler](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php)
.
I tried

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class A                     { public: void eat(){ cout<<"A";} }; 
class B: virtual public A   { public: void eat(){ cout<<"B";} }; 
class C: virtual public A   { public: void eat(){ cout<<"C";} }; 
class D: public         B,C { public: void eat(){ cout<<"D";} }; 

int main()
{
    A *a = new D(); 
    a->eat(); 

}
```

It worked . Then I wanted to invoke B's eat and changed A *a = new D();  to

```
 B *a = new D();
```

and this too worked .But when I tried

```
C *a = new D();
```

It threw and error

> error: 'C' is an inaccessible base of 'D'
>        C *a = new D();

Why with C alone this error ? It is even public . Then why its not accessible ?

So what  I did was I changed the order of inheritance to

```
class D: public         C,B { public: void eat(){ cout<<"D";} };
```

And now C *a = new D(); passed but B *a = new D(); failed .

Why is it so ?

Is the order important ?

When I googled I found this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328921/c-multiple-inheritance-order), but found that it is for constructors .
I could not understand why this case fails .

Please forgive if my question is stupid , as I am damn new to C++ .I am used to only java where there is no multiple inheritance .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`D` inherits publicly from `B`, but *privately* from `C`. Use this if you want to inherit publicly from both:

```
class D: public B, public C { public: void eat(){ cout<<"D";} };
```

Comment: oh If I right as I haven't specified public for C it assumed private ... Am I right ?

Comment: Correct for `class`es, it's the opposite for `struct`s.