# Changing inheritance order produces different results

Tags: c++, inheritance

I was reading Thinking in C++, and found this piece of code:

```
//: C06:Persist1.cpp
// Simple persistence with MI

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class Persistent {
    int objSize; // Size of stored object
    public:
    Persistent(int sz) : objSize(sz) {}
    void write(ostream& out) const {
    out.write((char*)this, objSize);
    }
    void read(istream& in) {
        in.read((char*)this, objSize);
    }
};
class Data {
    float f[3];
    public:
    Data(float f0 = 0.0, float f1 = 0.0,
        float f2 = 0.0) {
        f[0] = f0;
        f[1] = f1;
        f[2] = f2;
    }
    void print(const char* msg = "") const {
        if(*msg) cout << msg << " ";
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cout << "f[" << i << "] = "
        << f[i] << endl;
    }
};
class WData1 : public Persistent, public Data {
public:
    WData1(float f0 = 0.0, float f1 = 0.0,
        float f2 = 0.0) : Data(f0, f1, f2),
    Persistent(sizeof(WData1)) {
        cout<<"size of w1 "<<sizeof(WData1)<<endl;
    }
};
class WData2 : public Data, public Persistent {
public:
    WData2(float f0 = 0.0, float f1 = 0.0,
        float f2 = 0.0) : Data(f0, f1, f2),
    Persistent(sizeof(WData2)) {
        cout<<"size of w2 "<<sizeof(WData2)<<endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    {
        ofstream f1("f1.dat"), f2("f2.dat"),f3("f3.dat"), f4("f4.dat");
        WData1 d1(1.1, 2.2, 3.3);
        WData2 d2(4.4, 5.5, 6.6);
        WData1 d3(1.1, 2.2, 3.3);
        WData2 d4(4.4, 5.5, 6.6);
        d1.print("d1 before storage");
        d2.print("d2 before storage");
        d3.print("d3 before storage");
        d4.print("d4 before storage");
        d1.write(f1);
        d2.write(f2);
        d3.write(f3);
        d4.write(f4);
    } // Closes files
    ifstream f1("f1.dat"), f2("f2.dat"),f3("f3.dat"), f4("f4.dat");

    WData1 d1;
    WData2 d2;
    WData1 d3;
    WData2 d4;
    d1.read(f1);
    d2.read(f2);
    d3.read(f3);
    d4.read(f4);
    d1.print("d1 before storage");
    d2.print("d2 before storage");
    d3.print("d3 before storage");
    d4.print("d4 before storage");
} ///:~
```

It produces unexpected output: Objects of class WData1 are persisted correctly, but objects of WData2 aren't. While trying to find the source of problem, and possible fix, I found out, that problem is only in reading WData2 (its stored correctly in the file).
To make this code work as intended, I had to change inheritance order from:

```
 WData2 : public Data, public Persistent{...
```

to

```
 WData2 :  public Persistent, public Data{...
```

I'm curious why inheritance order makes difference in this case. Shouldn't it make no difference?

Comment: [Here's an ond SO answer that seems relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17328962/440558), and don't forget to read the comment by Mat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in the class Persistent you use `this` to point to the beginning of the memory you want to `read/write`. This is a problem because you use this as an inherited class. Thus unless `Persistent` is not the first class inherited, `this` will not point to the beginning of the base class:

This is what we have for `Wdata1` and `Wdata2` (padding and alignment ignored):

```
      Wdata1
      +-----------+----------------------+
      | objSize   |  f[0]   f[1]   f[2]  |
      +-----------+----------------------+
      |Persistent |        Data          |
      ^
      |
this (of Persistent)

      |<-   what you read/ write       ->|



      WData2
      +----------------------+-----------+
      |  f[0]   f[1]   f[2]  | objSize   |
      +----------------------+-----------+
      |        Data          | Persistent|
                             ^
                             |
                    this (of Persistent)

                             |<-   what you read/ write       ->|
```

Comment: This kind of persistance looks awful, but it works in my machine. The problem is that, 2nd one doesn't. I read the strucure of the same class that I write, so data member layout shouldnt matter, as I read and write entire content of the class IMO

Comment: Lets look at WData2. It's layout may look like: float float float int. There maybe optional padding. As machine saves the memory from begging of the object, and ending at the begging of the object+its size, it should restore that object after writing content to memory that previously was read.

Comment: see my edit about `this`. That is your core problem. But the rest is still worth considering.

Comment: I still don't understand. "this" at WData2 points to Persistent part of class, which isn't beggining? Then if i read from this, ending at this+size i read the content of memory of Persistent and some that doesn't belong to WData2 object, but something else?

Comment: yes, because you don't use `this` of `Wdata2`, you use `this` of `Persistent`.

Comment: Thanks for the credit, but my answer is useless, as I noted in an update.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the calls in `Persistent`:

```
out.write((char*)this, objSize);
in.read((char*)this, objSize);
```

Here, `this` is a `Persistent*` and it is assumed to point to the beginning of the full object. That is only true if `Persistent` is the very first base class.

To work everywhere you can do this little known trick:

```
void *that = dynamic_cast<void*>(this);
out.write((char*)that, objSize);
in.read((char*)that, objSize);
```

The `dynamic_cast<void*>()` guarantees that you'll have the pointer to the most derived object.

**WARNING!**: Alas! This will not work unless the type is *polymorphic*. And the `Persistent` trick will not work with polymorphic types. So this answer, as it is, is useless. I am not deleting it because it may still be interesting why you shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem might be cause your base-class initialization in the `WData2` constructor initialization list. You need to call the base constructors in the same order you inherit the base classes.

So change

```
WData2(...) : Data(...), Persistent(...) { ... }
```

to

```
WData2(...) : Persistent(...), Data(...) { ... }
```