# Why this crosscast works differently?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I found that following simplified example works differently with GCC and Clang:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Body
{
public:
    virtual ~Body()
    {
        std::cout << "Body::~Body()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class HydrophobicObject : public virtual Body
{
};

class ControlledObject : public virtual Body
{
};

class CrawlingObject : public virtual ControlledObject
{
};

class OwnerProtection
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "OwnerProtection::f" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Caterpillar : public CrawlingObject, public OwnerProtection, HydrophobicObject
{
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Caterpillar caterpillar;
    Body& body = caterpillar;
    auto p = dynamic_cast<OwnerProtection&>(body);
    p.f();
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile and run this with Clang then no bad_cast exception happens. If I compile
and run this with GCC, I get bad_cast. But if I add "public" before HydrophobicObject then it works with GCC too.

Why "public" matters here for GCC and which compiler is correct here?

Update:
I use macOS Clang:

```
$ clang -v
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: I'll bet you could remove lots of code from this example and still show the problem.

Comment: Why `public virtual` here for the various base classes? Why the cast at all?

Comment: [Throws with clang](https://godbolt.org/z/rW3xav4P5) for me, too. I must admit I don't quite understand why.

Comment: @tadman this is simplified example of real code from old game project. I guess cast was used to check if body object has OwnerProtection property. So this is some kind of game logic

Comment: if you change the order of the inheritance to have Owner first, it seems to work okay for me. https://godbolt.org/z/v4EMqKboh

Comment: some more pertinent information too... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328921/c-multiple-inheritance-order

Comment: @g19fanatic I don't see how that 3 cases from answer could produce bad cast here